# Add string at the end of every loop but not for the last loop

Tags: php

I am creating a function to set query vars as below.

```
function set_query_var(array $params)
{
    $count = count($params);
    $query_var = '?';        

    foreach ( $params as $key => $value)
    {
        $query_var .= $key . '=' . $value .
        (($count > 1) ? '&' : NULL);
    }

    return $query_var;
}
```

Above function works fine but only issue is that, it is adding `&` to the end loop which I don't want.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like you're reinventing the wheel: [`http_build_query()`](http://us1.php.net/http_build_query)

Comment: @AlmaDo +1 and thanks a lot. I didn't know this function. It might be useful here to me.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I always use [`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode) and array:

```
function set_query_var(array $params)
{
    $query_var = [];        

    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $query_var[] = "{$key}={$value}";
    }

    return '?' . implode('&', $query_var);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful and optimized solution. Thanks a lot.... BTW `Alma Do` also gave me nice suggestion to use built in function.

Comment: @CodeLover yes, but my way is used more widely, not just for URL. I usually use it for SQL `WHERE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and dirty solution to you problem is to remove the last `&` from your string.

```
rtrim($string, "&");
```

would cut trailing `&`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function set_query_var(array $params)
{
    $count = count($params);
    $query_var = '?';        

    foreach ( $params as $key => $value)
    {
        $query_var .= $key . '=' . $value .
        (($count > 1) ? '&' : NULL);
    }
    $query_var = rtrim( $query_var, "&");
    return $query_var;
}
```